# How to save the contents into the xml file

Tags: xml, dom

I have a php code , I use it to store files to add content to xml.xml , but it is overwritten , I want it to be creating a next line , please guide me

```
<?php

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', "UTF-8");

    $element = $dom->createElement('ukthi');
    $dom->appendChild($element);

    $node_moi = $dom->createElement('dayla');
    $node_moi2 = $dom->createElement('dayla2');

    $node_moi->nodeValue = $_POST['ho_ten'];
    $node_moi2->nodeValue = $_POST['ngay_sinh'];

    $element->appendChild($node_moi);
    $element->appendChild($node_moi2);

    $dom->save('xml.xml');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your really want to append, use file_put_contents  with  flag  FILE_APPEND

But you should not do that with XML: you can add two xml content in a XML file.

You should have only one structure

1 first read actual xml file

2 append your node (note creating new xml)

3 save it like you do

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [saveXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) functions at the end of your `DOMDocument` creation:

```
file_put_contents("xml.xml", $dom->saveXML());
```